# Cognos Analytics will does not run after user selects prompts on prompt page

Tags: cognos

We have recently upgraded from Cognos 10.2.2 to Cognos Analytics 11.0.11.  Some users have had trouble running reports that include a prompt page.  After the prompt page is completed and they click **Finish**, it does not look like the report runs at all and they remain on the prompt page.  Internet Explorer 11 is being used and all browser history has been deleted.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem using the samples data?  If so, please provide the report spec for a simple report that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is resolved. Had to add display name to a text prompt that was on the prompt page that was causing the issue since migrating from 10 to 11.

Comment: "Display name" is not a property of a text box prompt.  Your answer does not explain how this issue was resolved.